# Google One Tap signout

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

I am implementing Google One Tap in my website, however I am unable to prevent the popup from spawning immediately after the logout. I know I could manually set a cookie for that, however the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/automatic-sign-in-sign-out) suggests to add the class `g_id_signout` to any link or button used for the logout. In my menu I have this entry:

```
<li>
    <a id="public-logout" class="g_id_signout" href="#logout"> <wk:text
        name="public_area.logout"/></a>
</li>
```

but the popup still shows immediately after the logout. For reference, the "X" button on the One Tap popup triggers the cooldown regularly. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Is the link dynamically created after Google One Tap library loaded?

If that's the case, the library cannot add correct event handler to this link.
You can try to add the click event handler by yourself with the example code below:

```
<li>
  <a id="public-logout" onclick="google.accounts.id.disableAutoSelect(); return true;" href="#logout"> <wk:text
    name="public_area.logout"/></a>
</li>
```

Or, you can bind the click event hander by JavaScript code.

More details at: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/reference/js-reference#google.accounts.id.disableAutoSelect